# Replace a value in particular position in a file

Tags: linux, awk

Can someone please help me here?

How do I replace 3 digit number value at poison 25 (25, 26, 27) from 478 to 645 in Unix script using AWK command. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your data look like and what does "478 to 647" refer to? This may be easier with Perl, depending on what the data looks like, would that be acceptable?

Comment: I need to add this replacement functionality to an existing Unix shell script. I need to read a file (input.txt), check if the value at position 25 is 479, then replace it as 647 and write entire record into a new file (input_new.txt).

Comment: What's a "record" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear about what "position 25" means, but this is actually a job `dd` is pretty good at, since it works with byte positions instead of lines:

```
current=$(dd if=file bs=1 skip=25 count=3 2>/dev/null)
(( current == 478 )) && dd if=<(printf 645) of=file bs=1 seek=25 conv=notrunc
```

If your definition of "position 25" is 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed, use "24" instead of "25".